# Tablesorter: Export to CSV and Retain Style

Tags: jquery, tablesorter, export-to-csv

Mottie's Tablesorter output widget is great and working well, but I'm having trouble getting it to respect any HTML applied to the cell. The table is to be imported into Excel via CSV.

- I have tried traditional tags: `<b>` inside the cell to bold the text.
- `output_includeHTML` is true
- Various css on the TD itself: `style='font-weight: bold; background: green;'`

Changing the HTML on the page here:
http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-widget-output.html

Didn't return formatted a CSV into Excel, so I'm not sure if it's even built in. I might be requesting more of a hacky way to get tablesorter to respect such styling.

Comment: So you want a formatted csv file...i think that is impossible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The output widget can export HTML in a csv file

```
21,"<span class='red'>John</span>",'Robin'\n\tHood,33,$19.99,25%,"Dec 10, 2002 5:14 AM"
```

When you load that into Excel, it won't interpret the HTML as anything but text.

[image]

If you want to retain the color and styling, you can just select the table content, then drag-and-drop the table into Excel ([ref](http://www.mrkent.com/tools/converter/))

[image]

Comment: Mottie, that drag-and-drop tip is invaluable. Thank you. Do you imagine that you'll ever develop a genuine .xls import? Just curious.

Comment: I don't have any plans to add that... maybe you want to check out [this plugin](http://wsnippets.com/export-html-table-data-excel-sheet-using-jquery/) ([source @ github](https://github.com/battatech/battatech_excelexport))?

Comment: Noted. Mottie, a quick question here. I have a table that loads, via AJAX, inside another table. It's a popup table. They both have CSV download buttons. On the popup, when I hit the CSV button, it should only download the popup's table, but instead I'm getting downloads for both the holding table and the popup table. In summary, the problem is: "get two downloads when triggering outputTable on a table that has a parent table. Both have the output widget." Is there a way around this?

Comment: In the table cell that contains the popup table, add a `data-name` attribute (attribute name set using `output_dataAttrib`) that contains a space. This will ignore the contents of that cell.